# Prevent release artifacts to be overwritten when using s3 to store maven artifacts

Tags: maven, amazon-s3, release-management

We are using Amazon S3 to manage the maven artifacts.

Currently, if we do `mvn deploy` , the release artifacts gets overwritten on Amazon s3.

Ideally the release artifacts should be immutable. How can we ensure the same?

Comment: Use Nexus or Artifactory to manage your artifacts.

Comment: Is there no possibility while using s3 to manage the artifacts?

Comment: The professional way is to use a professional tool.

Answer (score 1):

Check S3 Object Lock functionality. Probably it's what you are looking for. But be careful, with some policies object can be removed just together with an AWS account.